# AssertionError: assert t.graph == cond_graph when generating heatmap for LocallyConnected2D layer with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, heatmap

I'm trying to create a heatmap of the last [LocallyConnected2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LocallyConnected2D) layer (from tf.keras.layers, so no own implementation) of a publicly available [implementation](https://github.com/swghosh/DeepFace/blob/master/deepface/deepface.py) of [deepface](https://research.fb.com/publications/deepface-closing-the-gap-to-human-level-performance-in-face-verification/) (face recogntion/verification model) in Keras.

The heatmap I am  generating with this example [implementation](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/) from the keras website. The example works for me, but when I try to obtain the heatmap of the deepface model, I get an error which I don't get.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-7ff17cbeefd4> in <module>
----> 1 heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(img, model, last_conv_layer_name, classifier_layer_names)
      2 
      3 plt.matshow(heatmap)
      4 plt.show()

<ipython-input-10-3b61c4411dd2> in make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, classifier_layer_names)
     30     # This is the gradient of the top predicted class with regard to
     31     # the output feature map of the last conv layer
---> 32     grads = tape.gradient(top_class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)
     33 
     34     # This is a vector where each entry is the mean intensity of the gradient

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py in gradient(self, target, sources, output_gradients, unconnected_gradients)
   1046         output_gradients=output_gradients,
   1047         sources_raw=flat_sources_raw,
-> 1048         unconnected_gradients=unconnected_gradients)
   1049 
   1050     if not self._persistent:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\imperative_grad.py in imperative_grad(tape, target, sources, output_gradients, sources_raw, unconnected_gradients)
     75       output_gradients,
     76       sources_raw,
---> 77       compat.as_str(unconnected_gradients.value))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py in _gradient_function(op_name, attr_tuple, num_inputs, inputs, outputs, out_grads, skip_input_indices, forward_pass_name_scope)
    155       gradient_name_scope = "gradient_tape/"
    156     with ops.name_scope(gradient_name_scope):
--> 157       return grad_fn(mock_op, *out_grads)
    158   else:
    159     return grad_fn(mock_op, *out_grads)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\cond_v2.py in _IfGrad(op, *grads)
    169   # Resolve references to forward graph tensors in grad graphs and ensure
    170   # they are in-scope, i.e., belong to one of outer graphs of the grad graph.
--> 171   true_grad_inputs = _resolve_grad_inputs(true_graph, true_grad_graph)
    172   false_grad_inputs = _resolve_grad_inputs(false_graph, false_grad_graph)
    173 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\cond_v2.py in _resolve_grad_inputs(cond_graph, grad_graph)
    410     # `cond_graph`.
    411     if t.graph != grad_graph.outer_graph:
--> 412       assert t.graph == cond_graph
    413       # `internal_captures` are not treated as intermediates and hence not added
    414       # to If op outputs. So we get the outer tensor corresponding to those

AssertionError:
```

Does anyone maybe know what this error means and how I can solve it?
Thank you for your time!

Python version: 3.7.7 
Keras version: 2.3.1 
Tensorflow version: 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve this error, but migrating my model to tensorflow 2.0 and using this [heatmap implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58322147/how-to-generate-cnn-heatmaps-using-built-in-keras-in-tf2-0-tf-keras) worked.